# LDAPInvalidDNSyntaxResult error when binding LDAP connection in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, ldap, openldap, flask-login

I've got a Flask app that I'm trying to connect to my LDAP server ([OpenLDAP](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap)) using the [flask-ldap3-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, but I don't seem to be able to make a connection bind properly.

My environment variables are set to:

```
LDAP_HOST = 'openldap'
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'dc=example,dc=org'
LDAP_BIND_USER_DN = 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org'
LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD = 'admin'
LDAP_USER_DN = 'ou=users'
LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR = 'cn'
LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR = 'cn'
```

When I go to authenticate with `result = ldap_manager.authenticate(username, password)` I get a response saying:

```
LDAPInvalidDNSyntaxResult - 34 - invalidDNSyntax - None - invalid DN - bindResponse - None
```

and the result is therefore:

```
{'user_info': (None,), 'user_id': (None,), 'user_dn': (None,), 'user_groups': [], 'status': <AuthenticationResponseStatus.fail: 1>}
```

Here's my LDAP structure:

[image: phpLDAPadmin structure]

And here's an example user DN:
[image]

If I try to connect via the `ldapsearch` command, I get the proper response:

```
# ldapsearch -x -b "ou=users,dc=example,dc=org" -H "ldap://openldap" -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=users,dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# users, example.org
dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
ou: users
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

# gramsay, users, example.org
dn: cn=gramsay,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
givenName: Gordon
sn: Ramsay
cn: gramsay
uid: gramsay
userPassword:: <password>
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/users/gramsay
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top

# iausers, users, example.org
dn: cn=iausers,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
cn: iausers
gidNumber: 500
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 4
# numEntries: 3
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm connecting, or possibly the structure on my LDAP server?

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being that `flask-ldap3-login` was trying to do a direct bind with the provided username/password, instead of the admin credentials, which was not valid. Instead, I needed to set `LDAP_ALWAYS_SEARCH_BIND = True` to ensure that a search bind was executed instead of a direct bind.